# Limit number of characters allowed in TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

**How can I limit the maximum number of characters in TextField, I use maxLength property, but user can still able to type more than maxlenght.**

Here is my code:

```
     TextField(
              maxLength: 10,
              inputFormatters: [
                 LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
              ],
              maxLengthEnforced: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Details',
              ),
            )
```

[image]

Comment: Try using ```TextFormField``` instead of ```TextField```.

Comment: @Vineet I tried TextFormField, it has the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Try out below code**

```
inputFormatters: [
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(6), // set limit according to your requirment 
                                
                 ]
```

Use this property in your **textfield**

Comment: I tried inputFormatters by importing  'package:flutter/services.dart', but user can still able to type more than maxLength given.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67898). It's related to Gboard composing. Try to hit space and the text will be truncated to the limit.